# How random is the rand() function?

Tags: random

More specifically my question is, given infinite time will `int(rand()*1000)` eventually hit every number between 0 and 999?  What about 10^4, 10^5...  I guess it's guaranteed to break once you hit the size in memory, i.e. if rand() returns a float, which is say n bits in memory, you can't possibly hit more than n different integers, so once you got to `rand()*(2^n+1)`, you're guaranteed to miss some.

Comment: There is not a unique `rand( )` function; it can vary from language to language, and for some languages from implementation to implementation.  Please be more precise as to what language and platform you are asking about.

Comment: Can you indicate what `rand()` facility you're talking about?  Language, library, etc...  In general you're right that the number of possible outputs can be no greater than the number of possible inputs.

Comment: The majority of languages use LCG for their standard rand() due to its lightweight nature, although some do have more options.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, given infinite time it will hit every number in your range provided it has an infinite period; once the seed value is reached again the sequence repeats. Of course as you mentioned you would be limited the precision of the value returned by rand() and eventually you would hit a breaking point where it couldn't map onto every integer in a large enough range. But if you consider a theoretical computer with infinite precision and period (you brought up infinity), then you will hit every number in your specified range given infinite time.

However, rand() uses an LCG which does not give you a uniform distribution of numbers. That is, you'll get some number hit with a higher frequency than others (although with infinite time you would hit all since infinity is just that cool). If you require a uniform distribution, then use something like the Mersenne Twister algorithm. There's a random generator in the Boost libraries that has the Mersenne Twister and is easy to implement.

Comment: It might not be LCG in every language, but LCG is very common.

Comment: @Zach, my point is the question doesn't contain sufficient detail to answer.  An example:  Python currently uses the Mersenne Twister, not a linear congruential generator.  And exactly how many possible outcomes of this `rand()` call are there?  Is it a single, a double, a fraction?  Without knowing those details, you're just speculating.

Comment: The question is more theoretical on random generators, otherwise infinite time would not be mentioned, and you can generalize your answer to account for the different generators giving examples of the more common ones, such as LCG and MT. Also, you can handle precision in a generalized manner as well, since these algorithms are generalized for precision (eventually registers will be larger sizes than at present). Depending upon if performance or quality of randomness is a higher priority, you'd want to pick the algorithm accordingly, and there's also more options than LCG and MT.

Comment: Also, anybody can easily contrive a low quality generator such as in that cartoon. There's an infinite number of those algorithms as well...